# ASP.Net MVC Store User Entity In Session

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, entity, session-variables

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web application with Entity Framework 4. When a user logs into my application I would like to store their user entity (firstName, lastName etc) in a session which can then be access throughout the application.

I understand that this may not be a good idea because when the ObjectContext closes/ disposes, then the User entity is detached and the user details could be lost.

I thought another method could be, when the user logs in, assign the userID (Primary Key) to a session variable, ie:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUserID"] = user.userID;
```

Then create a class in the UserService class like so:

```
public static User CurrentUser
    {

        get
        {
            return Data.DBEntities.Users.Where(u => u.userID == HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUserID"]).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
```

Which should return a User Entity based on the currentUserID session variable. This isn't working for me however, I am getting a couple of errors

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
Delegate 'System.Func<Asset.Model.User,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
```

Is this approach I am taking correct, or is there a better way?

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, don't store security-sensitive information in `Session`. Google "ASP.NET Session hijacking" for info as to why.

That said, this code can be made to work. You just have a cast error. Also, You're not accounting for the fact that `Session` can and *does* expire during a login. You could do this:

```
public static User CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        object userID = HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUserID"];
        if (userID == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Oops!");
        }
        return Data.DBEntities.Users.Where(u => u.userID == (int)userId ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

...which at least compiles, but isn't secure and sometimes throws.

**It would be better to store the user ID on a [custom principal](http://www.asp.net/security/videos/use-custom-principal-objects), which is secure and doesn't expire.**

Answer (score 0):

You can store whole entity in Session. It will be detached but it doesn't mean that it will lost values - only in case of lazy loading you will not be able to lazy load navigation properties.

In your current code try to get your `currentUserId` to temporary variable and use that variable in your query.

Comment: Aside from the two problems already mentioned in my answer, this introduces the additional risk that your app might fail at runtime if you (1) switch to a distributed session store and (2) have any non-serializable properties. That said, I think "insecure and unreliable" are reasons enough not to put this in `Session` even without the additional risk. `Session` is a user-specific cache, not a general-purpose, secure data store.